# My app crashes when I do action of pressing home button and launching app repeatedly.(Failed to scene update in time )

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

App crashes with repeated action of pressing home button and relaunching app again.
It shows error : "App Identifier" failed to scene-update in time.
what may be the cause. I am not able to figure out main problem

```
    Incident Identifier: 27CC9739-D51D-4FB5-93F3-7BA8C77572BA
    CrashReporter Key:   a07333ad8a068158ccf8ed11924ed38b859af24b
    Hardware Model:      iPad3,4
    Process:             App name [4854]
    Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle  /Application/90CB07D8-0D01-4C03-AB81-4F4C6F3360A9/AppName.app/AppName
    Identifier:          app.identifier
    Version:             3.1.1 (3.1)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2015-04-13 19:08:53.410 +0530
    Launch Time:         2015-04-13 19:07:54.641 +0530
    OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  00000020
    Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
    Highlighted Thread:  0

   Application Specific Information:
   appIdentifier failed to scene-update in time

   Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 11.480 (user 11.480, system 0.000), 56% CPU 
   Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 10.050, 49% CPU

   Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x17fd2370
   Thread 0:
   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x36d7e2a0 access + 8
   1   libsqlite3.dylib                 0x36a4f4fa 0x36a33000 + 115962
   2   libsqlite3.dylib                 0x36a4ec9c 0x36a33000 + 113820
   3   libsqlite3.dylib                 0x36a4e53c 0x36a33000 + 111932
   4   libsqlite3.dylib                 0x36a627a6 0x36a33000 + 194470
   5   libsqlite3.dylib                 0x36a60ed6 sqlite3_step + 414
   6   CoreData                         0x28aa6ab8 _execute + 96
   7   CoreData                         0x28aa67ae -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 1842
   8   CoreData                         0x28b8e2b2 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1002
   9   CoreData                         0x28ad75c8 -[NSSQLCore newFetchedPKsForSourceID:andRelationship:] + 2292
   10  CoreData                         0x28ad63ec -[NSSQLCore newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 760
   11  CoreData                         0x28b5ab4c __110-  [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 148
   12  CoreData                         0x28b607c8 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 260
   13  libdispatch.dylib                0x00632ad4 0x631000 + 6868
   14  libdispatch.dylib                0x0063a264 0x631000 + 37476
   15  CoreData                         0x28b54302 _perform + 130
   16  CoreData                         0x28ad6064 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 220
   17  CoreData                         0x28ad5e12 -[NSFaultHandler retainedFulfillAggregateFaultForObject:andRelationship:withContext:] + 598
   18  CoreData                         0x28af49e4 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] + 400
   19  CoreData                         0x28ad8da8 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet count] + 20
   20  CoreData                         0x28af2732 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _propagateDelete:] + 1218
   21  CoreData                         0x28af20be -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _propagateDeletesUsingTable:] + 542
   22  CoreData                         0x28af1e50 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processDeletedObjects:] + 664
   23  CoreData                         0x28acfabc -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _propagatePendingDeletesAtEndOfEvent:] + 180
   24  CoreData                         0x28acec5e -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1410
   25  CoreData                         0x28acdcf6 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 218
   26  AppName                          0x000cd0d2 +[DataDownloader removeDataFromClass:] (DataDownloader.m:2063)
   27  AppName                          0x000cb6ee -[DataDownloader DeleteTablesFromDb:] (DataDownloader.m:1924)
   28  AppName                          0x000bcdac -[DataDownloader downloadContentsData] (DataDownloader.m:395)
  29  Foundation                        0x29aa77c4 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 464
  30  CoreFoundation                    0x28d694bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
  31  CoreFoundation                    0x28d69036 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 646
  32  CoreFoundation                    0x28d67286 __CFRunLoopRun + 1414
  33  CoreFoundation                    0x28cb561c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
  34  CoreFoundation                    0x28cb542e CFRunLoopRunInMode +  102
 35  GraphicsServices               0x3003b0a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
 36  UIKit                          0x2c2a0354 UIApplicationMain + 1436
 37  AppName                            0x000ab370 main (main.m:17)
 38  libdyld.dylib                  0x36cc9aac start + 0

  Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
  Thread 1:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d7c2a0 kevent64 + 24
  1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x0063f674 0x631000 + 58996
  2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x006345ae 0x631000 + 13742

  Thread 2:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d909cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0aea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ab80 start_wqthread + 4

  Thread 3 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
  Thread 3:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d7c4f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
  1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d7c2e4 mach_msg + 36
  2   CoreFoundation                    0x28d68b4e     __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
  3   CoreFoundation                    0x28d670f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
  4   CoreFoundation                    0x28cb561c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
  5   CoreFoundation                    0x28cb542e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
  6   libAVFAudio.dylib                 0x279c771a GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 130
  7   libAVFAudio.dylib                 0x279b9c38 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 192
  8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce90 _pthread_body + 136
  9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce02 _pthread_start + 114
  10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ab8c thread_start + 4

  Thread 4 name:  com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
  Thread 4:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x36d7c4f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x36d7c2e4 mach_msg + 36
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x28d68b4e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x28d670f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x28cb561c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x28cb542e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
 6   AudioToolbox                   0x28474cb2 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 130
 7   AudioToolbox                   0x2845cdf2 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 206
 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x36e0ce90 _pthread_body + 136
 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x36e0ce02 _pthread_start + 114
 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x36e0ab8c thread_start + 4

 Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
 Thread 5:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x36d7c4f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x36d7c2e4 mach_msg + 36
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x28d68b4e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x28d670f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x28cb561c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x28cb542e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
 6   CFNetwork                      0x2886e3da +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
 7   Foundation                     0x29ab2386 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x36e0ce90 _pthread_body + 136
 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x36e0ce02 _pthread_start + 114
 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x36e0ab8c thread_start + 4

  Thread 6 name:  AFNetworking
  Thread 6:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d7c4f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
  1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d7c2e4 mach_msg + 36
  2   CoreFoundation                    0x28d68b4e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
  3   CoreFoundation                    0x28d670f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
  4   CoreFoundation                    0x28cb561c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
  5   CoreFoundation                    0x28cb542e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
  6   Foundation                        0x299ed428 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 260
  7   Foundation                        0x29a3b8e8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
  8   AppName                           0x0013783a +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:167)
  9   Foundation                        0x29ab2386 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
  10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce90 _pthread_body + 136
  11  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce02 _pthread_start + 114
  12  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ab8c thread_start + 4

  Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
  Thread 7:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d9008c __select + 20
  1   CoreFoundation                    0x28d6d31a __CFSocketManager + 494
  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce90 _pthread_body + 136
  3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce02 _pthread_start + 114
  4   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ab8c thread_start + 4

  Thread 8:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d7c4f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
  1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d7c2e4 mach_msg + 36
  2   CoreFoundation                    0x28d68b4e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
  3   CoreFoundation                    0x28d670f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
  4   CoreFoundation                    0x28cb561c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
  5   CoreFoundation                    0x28cfe286 CFRunLoopRun + 94
  6   CoreMotion                        0x295b6dee 0x29578000 + 257518
  7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce90 _pthread_body + 136
  8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ce02 _pthread_start + 114
  9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ab8c thread_start + 4

  Thread 9:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x36d909cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0aea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x36e0ab80 start_wqthread + 4

  No thread state (register information) available
  Binary Images:
      0xa7000 - 0x332fff AppName armv7        <c2fa8b9a84e93ba591453300c1bdd6ab> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle      /Application/90CB07D8-0D01-4C03-AB81-4F4C6F3360A9/AppNAme.app/AppNAme
0x614000 - 0x61bfff libBacktraceRecording.dylib armv7s        <52f18c658c9e391cbd9c4f3c1ec0236b> /Developer/usr/lib      /libBacktraceRecording.dylib
      0x623000 - 0x62afff libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib armv7s  <e43afd4915303efcbabe6f3a8ab8b721> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
      0x631000 - 0x654fff libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <1a5ef03f49fb37a8840857bb300d3404> /usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib
      0x1fe8c000 - 0x1feaffff dyld armv7s  <a5945c39ff6d340f809804781b24106d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x27841000 - 0x279adfff AVFoundation armv7s  <291c7a621b65396491697e7a7f728b16> /System/Library/Frameworks      /AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
      0x279ae000 - 0x27a0cfff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <1b452a7a75513cf9aa82e59feb7eef33> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
      0x27a46000 - 0x27a46fff Accelerate armv7s  <3b40c742a7323214a5eb836630536bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
      0x27a57000 - 0x27c72fff vImage armv7s  <844c5a129a2f3dbe9c0b23824f3254f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
      0x27c73000 - 0x27d59fff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <aaaefc0f51f23049871f65ea9c4c7151> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
      0x27d5a000 - 0x2801efff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <ba74aac653423b3b9bae4122d84935d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
      0x2801f000 - 0x28030fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7s  <3df96b6a86303adea6abea68b7b610ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
      0x28031000 - 0x280adfff libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <fb3e0b030cc5346c89af71af2d17bc27> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
      0x280ae000 - 0x280c0fff libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <abd4670b295c3f50a2658d0f3f86d78c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
      0x280c1000 - 0x280c1fff vecLib armv7s  <9495c9829e28344fb1820d2140fcaf35> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
      0x280c2000 - 0x280e8fff Accounts armv7s  <cf7ceabb9af233f0b657f23423988703> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
      0x280e9000 - 0x280e9fff AdSupport armv7s  <e8991cf968f936d7bcc5ae162b5ede1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
      0x280ea000 - 0x2815afff AddressBook armv7s  <eeeabdf6b9703b4f846b672d0bb50eeb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
      0x2815b000 - 0x2827ffff AddressBookUI armv7s  <6fe5557b059b3ff38179c43183cfe8c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
      0x28292000 - 0x28416fff AudioCodecs armv7s  <701a15a9b4c2355a930d5f52b9cb582b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
      0x28417000 - 0x2868afff AudioToolbox armv7s  <5cf7594c3e8e33a889f26f9d2b8f74b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
      0x287f2000 - 0x28979fff CFNetwork armv7s  <79b211df401f377fb05acc07a57db3ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
      0x2897a000 - 0x289fafff CloudKit armv7s  <aa1d623f3be434a6a75d2e49b41d26b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
      0x289fb000 - 0x28a5afff CoreAudio armv7s  <5b3129e5e3c23c4fb1052346c18e63b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
      0x28a73000 - 0x28a90fff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <2040fbe8e91833e5a14c2e4961b5995b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
      0x28a91000 - 0x28c9cfff CoreData armv7s  <db7e2287362438249bb753788c64a2b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
      0x28c9d000 - 0x28fc9fff CoreFoundation armv7s  <a76fd43513ee3af9af444082a92ad639> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
      0x28fca000 - 0x290f4fff CoreGraphics armv7s  <a3d08c6b246236fd9a078619f6c2010b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
      0x29134000 - 0x29136fff libCGXType.A.dylib armv7s  <8c8f282d69573460983d78cbaebfd8cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
      0x29137000 - 0x29141fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7s  <795fcab613223b6d833937453beb1048> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
      0x29329000 - 0x29344fff libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <ae6bf33909b531b6abae4b007d9dd46b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
      0x29345000 - 0x29453fff CoreImage armv7s  <0dd5152defdf3200b22c29876b05e34b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
      0x29454000 - 0x294abfff CoreLocation armv7s  <9bdb875e9e8939cab03d223432e87ec8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
```

Comment: Why are you doing something like this ? AFAIU you are trying to launch and quit the app at the same time repeatedly. This feels normal thinking in terms of these.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the main thread for too long a time while the app is becoming active.  The class name `DataDownloader` is extremely suspicious and sounds like something that should be passed off to a background thread.

Basically, any time you see a crash with "Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d" you should investigate some way to defer whatever is happening on thread zero to a later time or move it off the thread that blocks the user interface.

Comment: Thanks philip, problem was with DataDownloader class. Crash resolved by implementing core data on multiple thread.